# Adding and positioning Array of UIButtons in UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uibutton

At the beggining, here is the [screenshot of my ViewController in Action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u6zC7.jpg). 
My `ViewController` is contained of Embedded YouTube video, below it is `UIScrollView` and under him is `UITableView` which is for now randomly populated. I want to get all the albums from the specific singer, and for each of them, a seperate `UIButton` as shown in screenshot ->

> svi, lek za spavanje, balkan

The thing is, I will get all the albums from `YouTube API`, so I do not know how many albums singer has got. I have to add UIButtons programmatically in Swift.

On my language, "svi" means "all", so when I click "svi" I should get all the albums listed below it in `UITableView`. Similarly, all the albums and "svi"("all") should be in `UIScrollView`, so when the user clicks, for example, "Balkan", `UITableView` should be populated with all the tracks from that "Balkan" album.

Can anyone suggest me how to make and position all the `UIButtons` (`as an Array of UIButtons`) in `UIScrollView` according to the screenshot provided at the top? Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add Scrollview in storyboard / add programatically
2. Have a array with list of albums
3. Create `UIButton` programatically and add it to scroll view
4. Set size of the scrollview at the end.

Code snippet as follows,

```
   UIScrollView * scView;
   UIButton * btn;
   NSMutableArray * array;
   float btnWidth = 44;
   for(int i=0;i<array.count;i++) {
    btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(i*btnWidth, 0, btnWidth, 44);
    [btn setTitle:[array objectAtIndex:i]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTapped) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [scView addSubview:btn];
}
[scView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(btnWidth*array.count, 50)];

- (void)btnTapped {
  // button click call back method
}
```

Check the size of the string with following method

```
- (CGSize)getHeightForText:(NSString *)text havingWidth:(CGFloat)widthValue andFont:(UIFont *)font {
CGSize size = CGSizeZero;
if (text) {
    CGRect frame = [text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(widthValue, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName:font } context:nil];
    size = CGSizeMake(frame.size.width, frame.size.height);
}
return size;
}
```

Pass your album name to this method and it returns `CGSize`, from that get width and set that width value to button width in above for loop.

Comment: I've clearly said that language is Swift. By the way, thanks for the idea.

Comment: Didn't notice, hope you can use this logic. Everything remains same just have to change the syntax.

Comment: Yeah. Of course, changed it and done everything you wrote. Now I get something like this, which is ugly. http://prntscr.com/9qec5g

Comment: But, I still have a problem.
http://prntscr.com/9qef3c
let btnWidth: CGFloat = 150
btn.frame = CGRectMake((CGFloat)((CGFloat)(i)*btnWidth), 0, btnWidth-100, 53)
these values work, but the button isn't wide enough. If I strech him, layout breaks.

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Again its a Objective-C code. :)

Comment: first parameter is myArray[i], second is btnWidth and third? how do i get the font from UIFont?

Comment: That will be the font which you set to your UIButton.